# Аналог svn properties keyword в git

Tags: git, svn

В **svn**  можно было задать `svn properties keyword`. В файле, который я коммитила сохранялись автор и путь до файла.

Какие подобные варианты могут быть в гите ?

Comment: в гите также можно посмотреть, кто коммитил файл и что менял. "Базовая версия" `git log имя-файла`.

Comment: Вот об этой возможности речь? http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html

Comment: Marvel, это «тяжёлое наследие», надобность которого в современных *vcs*-ах просто отпала: в распределённых системах **вся** история изменений доступна локально, без необходимости доступа ни к сети вообще, ни к «централизованному бутылочному горлышку» в частности.

Comment: Как там ваша задача, получилось ли решить?

Answer (score 3):

В каждом коммите, который вы делаете в Git, сохраняется множество данных, в том числе:

- Дата и время коммита
- Имя автора коммита
- email автора коммита

> автор и путь до файла.

Поскольку коммит — это снимок рабочей области, то путь до каждого файла (относительно корневой директории вашего репозитория) в нём тоже сохраняется.

Все эти данные хранятся в каждом репозитории Git, в том числе в том, в который вы делаете коммиты на вашей рабочей машине.

Как прочитать все эти данные? Используя команду [`git log`](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log). Без параметров и аргументов она выведет просто историю последних коммитов:

```
$ git log 

commit 7342397c6d9302b0c1e3672acdd8087a0442f031
Author: Nick Volynkin <nick.volynkin@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Aug 31 01:48:03 2015 +0600

    better regex, human-readable logging, data-driven tests with named datasets

commit bf5b57f2bc288da6d5309f0fa996fce9a66e09c4
Author: Nick Volynkin <nick.volynkin@gmail.com>
Date:   Sun Aug 30 01:16:20 2015 +0600

    two more datasets; tests use improved category switching
...
```

Вы можете запросить лог только по интересующему вас файлу:

```
$ git log pom.xml

commit 180b5903982baf08533b4975b00552e554067825
Author: Nick Volynkin <nick.volynkin@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Aug 29 15:21:50 2015 +0600

    added plugins to pom.xml, introduced test packages

commit d9db6ac0e39e995e718b842b59a871e9e66cf6df
Author: Nick Volynkin <nick.volynkin@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Aug 28 18:11:19 2015 +0600

    added basic files
```

Формат и состав выводимых данных полностью управляются с помощью различных параметров. Например, попробуйте следующие варианты. Каждый из них доступен как для всех файлов (без аргументов), так и для конкретного файла или пути (аргументом после параметров).

Краткий.

```
git log --oneline 
git log -s
```

Позволяет увидеть несколько ветвей и их взаимные отношения.

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
```

Параметр `--pretty=format:'...'` позволяет осуществлять тонкую настройку. Подробнее о нем можно прочитать в [руководстве](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log). Например, я использую такой alias для удобного мне вывода команды log:

```
log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit
```

Comment: Да, про команду git log я знаю. Вопрос в том что при коммите, гит автоматом должен прописывать путь и автора внутрь  файла (который я комичу)

Comment: @Marvel: объясните поподробнее, что должно происходить? Прямо в файл запись? А если это бинарник?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я попробую объяснить за автора вопроса: необходимо без доступа к «центральному» репозиторию получить историю изменений файла. в централизованных *vcs*-ах это было достаточно актуально. в децентрализованных, типа *git*-а — потеряло какой-либо смысл.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, эта информация бывает нужна **на стороне клиента** в продуктах распространяемых в виде исходного кода **без какого-либо Git**, для точной идентификации версии, о которой говорит конечный пользователь (например, множество клиентов, множество версий у разных клиентов несинхронизированных).

Comment: @LazyBadger: если вы имеете в виду версионирование документации, то я бы предложил осуществлять его средствами работы с документацией, но никак не VCS. Сталкивался с решением, когда документация пересобирается, тестируется и релизится одновременно с кодом, но технических подробностей, к сожалению, не знаю.

Answer (score 2):

- В Git нет keywords, и это - пунктик Линуса (читай - "и не будет")
- Если нужна легкая идентификация версии файла со стороны клиента (единственный реально полезный $Revision$ в SVN), то есть сравнительно легкий путь: [`ident` в .gitattributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion) и %ID% в тексте идентифицированных файлов (то, что пишется хэш не файла, а всего блоба - это уже ваши с Git сложности, найти в истории нужное все же можно), прочие *бесполезные красивости* так легко не получить
- Но если все же неймется, то есть smudge|clean фильтры (по линку же выше, даже с примером), которые теоретически могут делать любые преобразования/подстановки. Но это чисто клиентская часть, которая не передается при синхронизации репозиториев (если это важно) между разными рабочими местами, [метод решения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667200/git-attributes-smudge-clean-distributed-over-repos) - несколько косенький (переводить откровенно лень), но может работать